# Jetbrains Rider WPF Preview not loading

Tags: wpf, rider

My problem is that Jetbrains Rider doesn't load the preview for my WPF applications.
I use .Net 5.0.

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Anyone got the same problem or a solution?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to set `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`?

Comment: @Clemens No, you don't use that any more on .NET 5, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/sdk-and-target-framework-change

Comment: Just saw they prioritized it "Nice to have" https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-58358